# Use Django ORM in multiprocess spawn process

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

i need to use the Django ORM in some spawned process using python multiprocess module after doing some data collecting from many devices using SNMP protocol.

At this moment, this how i spawn the process:

```
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(insert_to_db, args)
```

Now, here is the issue: the function `insert_to_db` uses the django ORM to get some objects, check data consistency and save the new collected result to DB.

Actually, i can't start the spawned process using `fork` context due to some unidentified deadlocks.

My initial idea is to start a the process, inject the Django dependencies, and before doing the execution of the `insert_to_db` function execute the `django.setup()` to load all django things.

Anyone is able to give me a solution?

Comment: You can use [**`.bulk_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) this will likely boost efficiency more than multiprocessing

Comment: The problem is that before the create, i need to collect data from various devices using SNMP protocol.